# Lockdown command in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How would I go about making a lockdown command in discord.py (I just need the Members role to not be able to talk in any channel, here's the ID of the Members role if you need it: 799331763587383347)

Comment: What is your code? What have you tried? Stackoverflow community won't write code for you. Please read this: [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are you expecting us to do your homework? If so, we won't. We will, however, help you with any problems that you may face. Please check out the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you can use [TextChannel.set_permissions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.set_permissions) and make people not have permissions to speak, as shown below

```
async def my_command(ctx, channel:discord.TextChannel):
    await channel.set_permissions(myrole, send_messages=False) # where myrole is a discord.Role or discord.Member
    ...
```